# php BytesToStr перевести байты в строку для версии 5.4.16

Tags: php

на локальной машине написал функцию перевода байтов в строку
но на серваке не работает. ловит глобальную ошибку. из за ... версия сервака PHP Version 5.4.16
как исправить что бы такой же результат выдавало как на локалке

```
            function BytesToStr(array &$Buff)
            {
                return pack('C*', ...$Buff);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Оператор `...` используется в функции не только как "сборщик" всех аргументов в одну переменную, но и как "распаковщик" массива ($Buff - массив в вашем случае). Такая возможность появилась в PHP 5.6.

Как варианты решения:

1. Поменять версию PHP на сервере на более свежую (грозит появлением других ошибок, если проект, с которым работаете, писался для старых версий PHP)
2. Переписать функцию с использованием специальных функций подсчёта и обработки переданных аргументов: `func_num_args()`, `func_get_arg()`, `func_get_args()`
   (думаю, такой вариант устарел и будет медленее первого)